# PHP - Infinte for loop while splitting an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm splitting an array into five different arrays where all the first element in an array chunk goes to array $first and second to $second and so on, here's my full code. please help me.

```
<?php
$input = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50");

      $chunks = array_chunk($input, 5);

        $count = sizeof($chunks);
        $first = array();
        $second = array();
        $third = array();
        $fourth = array();
        $fifth = array();


       for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) 
      {
        $new = $chunks[$i];
        for($j=0;$j<5;$j++)
        {
          if($j=0)
          {
          $new[$j] = $first[$i]; 
          }
          elseif($j=1)
          {
          $new[$j] = $second[$i]; 
          }
          elseif($j=2)
          {
          $new[$j] = $third[$i]; 
          }

          elseif($j=3)
          {
          $new[$j] = $fourth[$i]; 
          }

          elseif($j=4)
          {
          $new[$j] = $fifth[$i]; 
          }
          else
          {
          echo "error";
          }

        }

      }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($first);
        print_r($second);
        print_r($third);
        print_r($fourth);
        print_r($fifth);
    ?>
```

I tried many ways but always end up in a infinite page loads on and on, and even crashes my firefox. I'm sitting with this for a whole day now, i just can't figure it out.

Comment: use foreach() instead of for for chunks.

Comment: there should be '==' in inner loop instead of just '=' while comparing in if else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use == conditional statement instead of assign statement, what happen here if you use assignment operator(=) in if condition, it always return true so your loop is going to infinite, also you have to assign  $first[$i] = $new[$j];

```
<?php
$input = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50");

$chunks = array_chunk($input, 5);

$count = sizeof($chunks);
$first = array();
$second = array();
$third = array();
$fourth = array();
$fifth = array();


for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    $new = $chunks[$i];
    for($j=0;$j<5;$j++)
    {
        if($j==0)
        {
            //$new[$j] = $first[$i];
            $first[$i] = $new[$j];
        }
        elseif($j==1)
        {
            $second[$i] = $new[$j];
        }
        elseif($j==2)
        {
            $third[$i] = $new[$j];
        }

        elseif($j==3)
        {
            $fourth[$i] = $new[$j];
        }

        elseif($j==4)
        {
            $fifth[$i] = $new[$j];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error";
        }

    }

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($first);
print_r($second);
print_r($third);
print_r($fourth);
print_r($fifth);
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

you are checking

```
$j=0
```

it should be

```
$j==0
```

if you use `$j = 0` it will always enter at first `if`

```
for ($j=0; $j<5; $j++)// $j value will be always 1 it will never increase. and $j < 5 will be always true that's why the loop is looping infinitely.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not checking if `j` is equal to a number but assigning `j` to a number.

Replace all yout `j=1//and the others` by `j == 1//and others`

Answer (score 0):

if condition is used for `checking` but you are doing assignment:

so use `==` instead of `=`

and i don't get it why you are doing :

```
 $new[$j] = $first[$i]; // where $first array is blank array
```

do this:

```
$first[$i] =$new[$j];// to assign the content of new to $first;
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, I am assuming you're trying to turn this:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50"]
```

Into this:

```
[["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50"]]
```

Then to this:

```
$first = ["1", "10"];
$second = ["2", "20"];
$third = ["3", "30"];
$fourth = ["4", "40"];
$fifth = ["5", "50"];
```

Let's go:

```
<?php
$input = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50");

$chunks = array_chunk($input, 5);

// See below on using foreach
// $count = sizeof($chunks);
$first = array();
$second = array();
$third = array();
$fourth = array();
$fifth = array();

// You may consider the foreach() construct:
//for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
foreach($chunks as $index => $new){
    // I've updated the following to work, but I think you can do this easier. See below.

    for($j=0;$j<5;$j++){
        // You may consider the switch syntax:
        switch($j){
            case 0:
                $first[$index] = $new[$j]; 
                break;
            case 1:
                $second[$index] = $new[$j];
                break;
            case 2:
                $third[$index] = $new[$j];
                break;
            case 3:
                $fourth[$index] = $new[$j];
                break;
            case 4:
                $fifth[$index] = $new[$j];
                break;
            default:
                echo "error";
                break;
        }
    }

    // I appreciate what you're doing, but if you're using hard variable names, you can:
    $first[] = $new[0];
    $second[] = $new[1];
    $third[] = $new[2];
    $fourth[] = $new[3];
    $fifth[] = $new[4];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($first);
print_r($second);
print_r($third);
print_r($fourth);
print_r($fifth);
?>
```

However, I would do it like so:

```
<?php
$input = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50");

$chunks = array_chunk($input, 5);

$places = array(array(), array(), array(), array(), array());

// Loop through the chunks
foreach($chunks as $chunk){
    // Use $key as the index number as it is the "place" in the chunk
    foreach($chunk as $key => $value){
        // The $array[] = syntax just adds one to the end of the array.
        // Since we're going in order anyways, we can trust this instead of specifying an index
        $places[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($places);

// And if you want: $first = $places[0]; $second = $places[1]; etc etc
?>
```